# Issues extracting Digital Multimeter Data readings from interface library via Python

Tags: c#, python, interface, usb, communication

Being a novice in Python and C#, and having reached a point with no significant progress, I'd like to ask for some suggestions.

Here is the issue I find:

I am trying to read the data from a Digital Multimeter through its C# library and targeting to export it into Python (being the only supported language of the target application).

The meter and communication interface libraries come from [Lcrrsearch](http://www.lcrresearch.com/downloads/).

Referring to the [instructions](http://www.lcrresearch.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/LCR_CIL_Guide_rev1-1.pdf) provided, I have run the C# project file and have succeeded in getting the readings (through FTD2XX_NET.dll, LCR_CIL.dll).

However, separately, when trying to use the .dll files in Python, I have failed to do so.

The solution paths I sought after were:

1. Calling the LCR_CIL.dll in Python via [Ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html)
2. Trying IronPython via Visual Studio for .NET
3. Using FTDI library to read the data from memory

Therefore, I would like to have some hints or ideas as to which path is the most straightforward one to import the data in Python and/or any similar example you could propose I would gladly welcome.

Comment: "...export it into Python (being the only supported language of target application)."  Can you clarify this?  Does this mean the target application exposes a Python API?  Does target application provide an interface for a common data transfer format like XML?

Comment: In your c#, you could write the data into a file, in JSON format.  Reading JSON text (here form the file) in Python is easy (https://developer.rhino3d.com/guides/rhinopython/python-xml-json/).  The libraries you talk about are for .NET (from your question), I doubt with will also work in Python.

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not find a target API for the application and no interface for XML data transfer. Citing the user manual about Python language integration says: "Python has been fully integrated into the SYSTEM 8 FormulaPlus calculator description language".